# Finding an element by XPath in Selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to navigate a webpage. There is a button I am trying to get to via its xpath. For other buttons on the site, it works fine. But for this particular one, I keep getting the error that the element can't be located. Firebug is just giving me the xpath in this format: //*[@id="continueButton"].

I notice that the button has wrappers around it. They are structured like

```
<div class = "cButtonWrapper">
  <div class = "cButtonHolder">
    <input type="image" id="continueButton" name="Continue" alt="Continue" src="/store/images/btn_continue.gif" value="Continue">
  </div>
</div>
```

Could the wrappers around the button have anything to do with not being able to locate it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `<input>` element cannot be properly located by XPath because you are using invalid HTML. Try using `<input id="continueButton"/>` or `<input id="continueButton"></input>` in your page source.